# Runtime.totalMemory() gives me a wrong value from configured -Xmx value in 64 bit jvm

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Configured -Xmx is 2037m (-Xmx2037), when getting total memory from
Runtime.totalMemory() it gives 136mb, How can i get exact configured xmx value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Runtime.maxMemory`, `Runtime.totalMemory` returns the current heap size.

Comment: I have configured -Xmx 400m but Runtime.maxMemory returns 355...
Why this fluctuation? Can I get exact Xmx value confifgured?

Comment: Good question. My answer is no. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729652/runtime-maxmemory-and-xmx

Answer (score 2):

`totalMemory` reports the current heap size, which grows only as needed towards the `Xmx` limit. `maxMemory` reports the maximum heap size.