# How to detect real value of -Xmx param? Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() is not accurate

Tags: java, memory, jvm

In my case this value is usually different than `-Xmx` that I'm specifying.

For `-Xmx810M` it returned `821035008` which is `783MB`. According to various (not truly reliable) sources it should return exactly the value specified by `-Xmx` parameter.

I look for:

1. Some reliable way of finding exact value of `-Xmx`
2. Some reliable source that will prove that `maxMemory()` is not accurate

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4391499 (which is from 2001, so it may have changed in newer versions of the JVM):

"The interpretation of the -Xmx flag is VM-dependent.  Some VMs,
including HotSpot, enforce a lower bound on the effective value of this option."

So as the previous answer stated, MaxMemory is accurate, and the Xmx flag is simply a suggestion.

The link above was found via an answer to an [earlier similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13729652/runtime-maxmemory-and-xmx) on SO.

And if you want to find the user specified value of Xmx, you could simply do roughly the following if using a Sun (ahem, Oracle) JVM/:

```
String commandLineInput = System.getProperty("sun.java.command");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("-Xmx(\\w*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(commandLineInput);
while(matcher.find()) {
  System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Runtime.maxMemory() is accurate.  It is the `-Xmx` option which is not.  How inaccurate it is depends on the version and I not sure what it is more of a hint than a precise setting.

When the totalMemory() matches your maxMemory() you are out of memory.